# Как контейнеры могут иметь свою файловую систему, если они запущены на 1 ПК?

Tags: docker, файловая-система

Изучаю Docker:

Команда docker run запускает процесс в изолированном контейнере. Процесс в
контейнере изолирован от хостовой системы и имеет свою собственную файловую и
сетевую систему.

Поясните, пожалуйста, как контейнеры могут иметь свою файловую систему, если они запущены на 1 ПК?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Comment: Файловая система это ровно то, что показывает процессу ядро ОС, ибо все обращения к файлам происходят исключительно с помощью вызовов функций ядра. docker пользуется возможностями современных ядер что бы показать процессу изолированное пространство, в том числе и виртуальную файловую систему